# Comments not visible in template even though they are saved in the database

Tags: python, django

I currently have 2 models in my App, one for uploaded files and another one for comments. I've figured out how to implement the forms on the same page and it seems to be working but for some reason, the submitted comments aren't being shown and I have no idea on how to accomplish that. Should I provide the comments in a return or seeing as that there is a ForeignKey in the Comment model this is not neccesary and the comments can be accessed through each file?

Each file will have it's own comments

```
# Model for all uploaded files
class Uploaded(models.Model):
    objects: models.Manager()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="users")
    time_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=MEDIA_ROOT)
    admintags = TaggableManager(blank=True, through=AdminTagsAll, verbose_name="Admin Tags")
    usertags = TaggableManager(through=UserTagsAll, verbose_name="User Tags")
    additional_description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.description} {self.file}"


# Model for comments
class Comment(models.Model):
    objects: models.Manager()
    file = models.ForeignKey('Uploaded', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

HTML template:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
                                            <div style="border:1px solid silver; border-radius:15px; padding:15px; margin:10px 0px;">
                                             <p class="mb-auto" style="font-size:15px;">{{ comment.text }}</p>
                                            </div>
                                        {% empty %}
                                            <div style="border:1px solid silver; border-radius:15px; padding:15px; margin:10px 0px;">
                                             <p class="mb-auto" style="font-size:15px;">No Comments</p>
                                            </div>
                                        {% endfor %}
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    url_parameter = request.GET.get("q")
    user = request.user
    files = Uploaded.objects.filter(user=user)
    userTags = UserTags.objects.all()
    form = FileUploadForm
    paginator = Paginator(files, 6)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    try:
        files_paginated = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        files_paginated = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        files_paginated = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    if url_parameter:
        filesSearch = Uploaded.objects.filter(user=user, name__icontains=url_parameter)
    else:
        filesSearch = Uploaded.objects.filter(user=user)
    context = {'form': form, 'page': page, 'files': files_paginated, 'userTags': userTags, 'comments':comments}

def add_comment_to_file(request, pk):
    file = get_object_or_404(Uploaded, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.file = file
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: where are you calling comments in `def index` ? because as i see, `comments is not defined`

Comment: you're sending in context the comments, but where you get that comments in the code?